# Mem-alternative on Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: memory, windows-7, 64-bit, cmd

I'm trying to get the free memory of the Windows 7 64 Bit system via a CMD command.

How can I realize?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at `systeminfo` ? It has a lot more info than what you're looking for, but it does have it. You'd have to parse it out (`systeminfo |find "Memory"`). It is also slow, so its usefulness depends on what you need this for.

---

In case anyone else comes looking and doesn't usually look past the accepted answer, **look below** at the answer provided by MBu, using WMI.

```
wmic os get FreePhysicalMemory
```

Comment: Just tried that, but this is way to slow :/ I'd need a command which can be executed in less than one second.

Comment: I believe this is the only standard windows command prompt utility that offers this, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this value from WMI with use of wmic:

```
wmic os get FreePhysicalMemory
```

This is equal to reading Win32_OperatingSystem.FreePhysicalMemory.